# Trying to using python for controlling games

Tags: python, python-3.x, keypress, simulate

I'm trying to use Python with win32api for controlling a game(Maplestory).My script runs perfectly on a lot of software such as Notepad, but except game.

I think maybe the game communicate directly with the hardware so that I could't use win32api to controlling game. But I can't figure out how to communicate with the hardware using a Python script. And I also didn't know who wrote a wheel could communicate with keyboard hardware.

These is my script:

```
import time,random,win32con,win32api

WAIT_TIME = 5

key_map = {
    "0": 49, "1": 50, "2": 51, "3": 52, "4": 53, "5": 54, "6": 55, "7": 56, "8": 57, "9": 58,
    "A": 65, "B": 66, "C": 67, "D": 68, "E": 69, "F": 70, "G": 71, "H": 72, "I": 73, "J": 74,
    "K": 75, "L": 76, "M": 77, "N": 78, "O": 79, "P": 80, "Q": 81, "R": 82, "S": 83, "T": 84,
    "U": 85, "V": 86, "W": 87, "X": 88, "Y": 89, "Z": 90
}

class Press:
    def __init__(self):
        print("The program will start in %d seconds" % WAIT_TIME)
        time.sleep(WAIT_TIME)
        self.time = time.time()
        pass

    def key_down(self, key):
        key = key.upper()
        vk_code = key_map[key]
        win32api.keybd_event(vk_code,win32api.MapVirtualKey(vk_code,0),0,0)


    def key_up(self, key):
        key = key.upper()
        vk_code = key_map[key]
        win32api.keybd_event(vk_code, win32api.MapVirtualKey(vk_code, 0), win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)


    def key_press(self, key):
        self.key_down(key)
        time.sleep(0.02)
        self.key_up(key)
        print(key)



class Illium(Press):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.spear = "A"
        self.bullet = "Q"
        self.buff1 = "3"
        self.buff2 = "4"

    def add_buff(self):
        if time.time() - self.time > 60:
            self.key_press(self.buff1)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            self.key_press(self.buff2)
            time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5,1))
            self.key_press("1")   # 
            self.time = time.time()

    def auto_attack(self):
        self.add_buff()
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5,1))  
        self.key_press(self.spear)
        time.sleep(random.uniform(1,1.5))
        self.key_press(self.bullet)
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5,1))




illium = Illium()
while True:
    illium.auto_attack()
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5,1))


print("ENd")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some games will take some measures to prevent script running(to prevent cheating).
Maybe using python script is not a good idea.

I don not play this game.If you really want to use python,maybe you can try other modules to control the game(such as pynput,pykeyboard and so on).

Comment: Do you think that switching to another library such as pykeyboard can solve these problems?

Comment: @Qfrost Have a try.But I recommend you use other tools to control the game.You can use autohotkey.I could use autohotkey to control Overwatch in the past.I do not know whether it would work in the game you play.

Comment: Ok, I try it tonight, thank you. But I still want to find a solution with python.